# Java ArrayList Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, xpath, arraylist, comparator

I need to create a comparator to sort arraylist with  a couple of xpaths and priority indicators...
First criterium is to sort xpaths in descending order, second criterium is: if paths are the same, path with higher priority will be first
Here is the list: xpath  priority

Before comparison:

```
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]            5
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1]  2 
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]/text()[3]  2
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[3]/text()[1]  4
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]/text()[1]  1
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[4]/text()[1]  3
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1]  3
```

After comparison:

```
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[4]/text()[1]  3
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[3]/text()[1]  4
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]            5
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]/text()[3]  2
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]/text()[1]  1
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1]  3
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1]  2
```

This is what I have so far, but it's not working properly :/

```
Collections.sort(mods, new Comparator<TextModification>() {
@Override
public int compare(TextModification  mod1, TextModification  mod2)
{

//Comapre paths
int pathComp =  mod2.getPath().compareTo(mod1.getPath());

//If mod2.path is "less" than mod1.path
if(pathComp < 0){
  if(mod1.getPath().startsWith(mod2.getPath())){
    return 1;
  }
}

//Return comparison
if(pathComp != 0){
  return pathComp;
}

//If paths are the same, sort by priority indicator
return mod2.getPriority() > mod1.getPriority() ? 1 : -1;
}
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What output are you getting? What type does `modn.getPath()` return?

Comment: Define not working properly. Is your unit test passing?

Comment: modn.getPath() returns xpath of object in array list, modn.getPriority() returns priority of xpath(int number)
Output which i get after comparison: `/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[4]/text()[1] 3
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[3]/text()[1] 4
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]/text()[1] 1
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2] 5
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]/text()[3] 2
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1] 3
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1] 2`
as you can see it causes problems with /HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2] ...

Comment: "if paths are the same, path with higher priority will be first " If they're the same, what difference does priority make?

Comment: after each path is written number(indication priority) so if you have:
`/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1] 1`
and
`/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1] 3`

they will be sorted this way
`/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1] 3
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1] 1`

Comment: What happens if you remove the first `if` block entirely? ie remove `if(pathComp < 0){if(mod1.getPath().startsWith(mod2.getPath())){return 1;}}`

Comment: @Bohemian i will get this output: `/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[4]/text()[1]
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[3]/text()[1]
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]/text()[3]
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]/text()[1]
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1]
/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[1]/text()[1]`
almost good, but `/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]` should be before `/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/P[2]/text()[3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sort in reverse path order, *except* when one path extends another. A simple work around is to add a high-ascii valued character ("z" is convenient) to the end of the path before comparing:

```
Collections.sort(mods, new Comparator<TextModification>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(TextModification mod1, TextModification mod2) {
        int pathComp = (mod2.getPath() + "z").compareTo(mod1.getPath() + "z");
        return pathComp == 0 ? mod2.getPriority() - mod1.getPriority() : pathComp;
    }
});
```

Note also the simplification of the code using a ternary operator and a priority *difference*.